# Local Security Policy "Lock pages in memory" set on my user account - why?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

I have a bit of a mystery that I am hoping the community can help me with.

I have 5 different servers:

- 3 Windows Server 2019 Datacenter VMs, joined to a corporate domain
- 2 Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard VMs, not joined to any domain

While looking through Local Security Policy settings

> Local Security Policy -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment

I was surprised to see my personal user account assigned "Lock pages in memory" rights. This seemed curious and more than a little risky.

- No other users or groups were assigned this right
- My personal account is a member of the local Administrators group, but I am not the only member, nor was I the first member (i.e. account not created during installation or setup)
- On the domain boxes, the permission was not assigned through any domain policy, but applied locally
- I never added this right, nor did any other human

I was very surprised to find this on the domain boxes because they were set up by our network provisioning team, who are very strict about rights assignments. But then I found the exact same thing on
the non-domain boxes that are under my complete control.

I am very aware of the debate around this setting regarding SQL Server, but only 2 of these boxes are running SQL Server.  The others have nothing SQL-related on them at all, not even SSMS. And besides, the SQL Server service account wasn't granted this right, my personal account was.

I'm not running any of the other culprits, like SAP or Oracle. I have a total of 7 non-domain boxes, some with this permission, some without, and I've done a comparison of all installed programs and there is no common denominator.  There's nothing odd installed on these boxes.  They have CrowdStrike, but not all the CrowdStrike boxes have this permission.

**Does anybody have any ideas how this permission could have been auto-added? Is there a program known to do this? What could possibly need this? What kinds of risks does this expose me to?**